# Does XGBoost use gradient descent?

Tags: boosting, gradient-descent, taylor-series

XGBoost is said to be based on "gradient tree boosting" in the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.02754). Reading the paper and the [introduction on the official website](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/model.html#), it seems to me that the algorithm does not use gradient descent. As far as I can tell, the second-order (Taylor expansion) approximation of the loss of the whole ensemble is used in each step, which corresponds to Newton-Raphson optimization (also known as *Newton boosting* in this context). In contrast, other gradient-boosting methods use the negative gradient of the previous loss function as a pseudo-response variable for the optimization of a new base learner, thus performing an additive version of gradient descent optimization.

Is XGBoost a gradient boosting method simply because it utilizes the gradient of the loss? Is it a gradient boosting method because it does use gradient descent, but I have failed to see it? Or is it, strictly speaking, not a gradient boosting method at all?

EDIT: The question's marked duplicate contains the answer indirectly. My question was aimed more towards terminology than the method itself. **XGBoost, in strict terms, does not perform gradient boosting but Newton boosting (in function space).** The answer can now also be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XGBoost#The_algorithm).